# Why does Html.PassowordFor print a placeholder as gibberish?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view where I have a Html.PasswordFor helper if the property which is linked to the helper has a value I set the following placeholder:

placeholder = "•••••••••••••••••"

However, the placeholder appears as gibberish.

`@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "•••••••••••••••••" })`

And the thing I get is the following:

[image]

I suppose the issue is with Razors encoding because the HTML element is created with the gibberish

[image]

Once I change the gibberish to dots in the dev console everything works fine.

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem, if your "•••••••••••••••••" is e.g. UTF-8 then your HTML charset must be UTF-8 as well (<meta charset="UTF-8">)

Comment: I just changed the charset to UTF-32 because it was UTF-8. I thought the same thing but it seems it is not from there. As i mentioned when I paste the dots in the browser dev console they render correctly I believe that is has something to do how razor renders these type of symbols.